# VBA: Offset based on column headers

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to offset to the right of a cell based on column headers?  I have some code that loops through a range, and if it finds a specific value it will offset 12 columns to the right.  Instead of saying  Offset(,12), is there a way I can say offset to the right in that same row to the column with the header I want?

For example if column B is named "host" and my range is

```
rng = ws.range("B1:B20")
```

and column N is named "country", I don't want to write:

```
offset(,12).value = ...
```

Instead if there is something like:

```
offset(to column: country).value =...
```

The reason I ask for this is to not specific an offset number to make the code more resilient to any changes that may happen to my excel worksheet.

I hope the explanation is clear. thanks!

Comment: Did you tried using Range names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Function below, will return the number of columns you need to `Offset` from your `Rng` to the "Header" you are looking for.

```
Option Explicit

Function OffesttoHeader(CurrentCol As Long, FindRng As Range, HeaderStr As String) As Long

    Dim HeaderRng As Range

    Set HeaderRng = FindRng.Find(what:=HeaderStr)
    If Not HeaderRng Is Nothing Then
        OffesttoHeader = HeaderRng.Column - CurrentCol + 1
    Else
        OffesttoHeader = -10000 ' raise to a large value >> as an error
    End If

End Function
```

---

***Test* Sub Code** (to test the function above):

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim NumberofCols As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  ' modify to your sheet's name
Set Rng = ws.Range("B1:B20")

' pass the following parameters:
' 1. Rng.column - in your case column B = 2
' 2. ws.Rows(1) - the Range to search for the Header, first row in ws worksheet
' 3. "Header" - the Header string you are searching for
NumberofCols = OffesttoHeader(Rng.Column, ws.Rows(1), "Header")

' raise an error message box
If NumberofCols = -10000 Then
    MsgBox "Unable to find Header"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked great. I just had to remove the "+1" from OffsetToHeader as it was one column too the right.  Was there a reason why you added this? Thanks!

Comment: @wra i might have got the calculations wrong, was calculating the difference, not the `Offset`

Comment: Oh okay, well otherwise it worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Thank you! How to edit the function such that the offset can be done to the left side and to the right side at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain the solution you seek above, use the Range.Find Method.

```
'Column Number
Dim clmCountry as Integer
```

From here, we want to find the header by using the Range.Find Method

```
'to find the header
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName")

    'update the range if necessary
    clmCountry = .Range("A1:Z1").Find("HeaderName").Column

End With
```

Once you've found the desired column, you may offset the following way:

```
... Offset(RowNum, clmCountry).Value = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to get a column value out of a row defined as a Range.

```
Public Function ProcessOneLine(row As Range) As String
```

This works for me

```
row.Offset(0,2).Value2 ' returns the value in Column 3
row.Offset(1,Range("C1").Column).Value2 ' also returns the value in Column
```

So use something like this:

```
Dim srcColumn as String
Dim colPosn as Integer
srcColumn = "C"
colPosn = Range(srcColumn & "1").Column
cellValue = row.Offset(0,colPosn-1).Value2
```